# De-duplicating when sending to data filters?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, filters, dataextensions

When I send to a data extension, I get the 'de-duplicate subscribers by email address' checkbox, which is great.

However, you *can't* do that when sending to a data filter.

Anyone know how you might? Maybe using Exclusion AMPScript?

Comment: Are you filtering a Data Extension or by Profile Attribute?

Comment: I'm filtering a Data Extension.

Comment: Although looking at it, I reckon I might be able to achieve what I want by using a 'Filtered Data Extension' instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an automation that first runs the filter and pushes the results to a sendable data extension. You could then de-dupe your send to that sendable data extension. Both steps could be added to the same automation, so running it would refresh the filter results in the sendable data extension, and then it would do your send.